# Issue in SOAP message generated by Embarcadero

Tags: soap

I have created an application developped by Embarcadero XE5 C++. I use THTTPRio to consume a web service.
I have a problem with the request message generated by our application. It seems that namespaces are missing in the soap message for NS1, NS2 and NS3.
I think there's a bug in the Embarcadero.

Here the SOAP request message generated by Embarcadero:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <G110Request xmlns="urn:wsdltypes.nmvs.eu:v1.0">
            <Header xmlns="urn:types.nmvs.eu:v1.0">
                <Auth>
                    <ClientLoginId>xxx</ClientLoginId>
                    <UserId>xxx</UserId>
                    <Password>xxx</Password>
                </Auth>
                <UserSoftware NS1:name="xxxxx" NS2:supplier="xxxx"/>
            </Header>
            <Body xmlns="urn:types.nmvs.eu:v1.0">
                <Product>
                    <ProductCode NS3:scheme="GTIN">1234567891234</ProductCode>
                </Product>
            </Body>
        </G110Request>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thanks for your help